# formation of SQL Statement using join

Tags: sql, database

I'm new to SQL. kindly help me in framing a SQL Statement for below scenario.

I have 2 tables and would like join both the tables.. Below u can find the statement which I have used for joining.

```
create table F5 (BT_TYPE int, appln int)
insert into F5 values(2,1)

create table LTB (Field int, lang int, Desc0 varchar(255))
insert into LTB values (1,1,'German')
insert into LTB values (1,2,'English')
insert into LTB values (1,3,'Itailian')
insert into LTB values (1,4,'Free lang')
insert into LTB values (2,1,'2German')
insert into LTB values (2,2,'2English')
insert into LTB values (2,3,'2Itailian')
insert into LTB values (2,4,'2Free lang')

select * from LTB
select * from F5

select a.*, b.Desc0 as bttyp_desc, c.Desc0 as appln_desc 
from F5 a, LTB b, LTB c 
where b.lang=1 and b.Field=a.BT_TYPE 
      and c.lang=1 and c.Field=a.appln
```

The expected result should be as shown below(highlighted one)

Kindly help me in framing the SQL Statement where same table name should not be used twice.

Comment: still not getting what exactly you want???

Comment: The expected result should be as shown below(highlighted one).. Where it is??

Comment: and what result right now you are getting??

Comment: why you have brackets in your where condition .. I don't think in case of only `and` condition you will be required these ..

Comment: http://bit.ly/1joqDIJ is the best solution for you

Comment: I'm getting the correct output, but I don't want to use same table name(LTB) twice.

Comment: As others have said, what is your desired results?  Regardless, some other notes: 1) Please don't use the implicit-join (comma-separated `FROM` clause) syntax, please always explicitly list your joins.  2) If you're doing something with storing languages, please store the ISO codes and names - and you'll need a separate table for the name translations.  3) Why do you have _two_ entries for each language?  4) It's spelled "Italian"

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm getting the correct output, but I don't want to use same table name(LTB) twice*

1. There is nothing wrong with joining `LTB` table twice
2. Consider using explicit ANSI style `JOIN` syntax instead of implicit comma-based one.
3. Don't use `SELECT a.*` in production instead explicitly specify columns you need.

That being said your query might look like

```sql
SELECT bt_type, appln, b.desc0 bttyp_desc, c.Desc0 appln_desc 
  FROM F5 a JOIN LTB b
    ON b.lang = 1 
   AND a.bt_type = b.field JOIN LTB c
    ON c.lang = 1 
   AND a.appln = c.field;
```

Now if for some reason you can't stand joining `LTB` twice you can rewrite the query using conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT bt_type, appln, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN field = BT_TYPE THEN desc0 END) bttyp_desc,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field = appln   THEN desc0 END) appln_desc
  FROM F5 a JOIN LTB b
    ON b.lang = 1 
   AND (a.bt_type = b.field OR
        a.appln = b.field)
 GROUP BY bt_type, appln
```

Output (in both cases):

```
| BT_TYPE | APPLN | BTTYP_DESC | APPLN_DESC |
|---------|-------|------------|------------|
|       2 |     1 |    2German |     German |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8c19/7)** demo

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?